# How to create two nested array

Tags: java, json, talend

I'm having a problem using `twriteJsonField` component as it does not allow to specify Multiple loop element

Is it posssible to do it in java ?

Really stack with that

my input is as below :

| Line_year | action | group | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | Action1 | group1 | comment1 |
| 2020 | Action2 | group2 | comment2 |

Now , i want to generate this json as output  :

```
    {
     "line_list":[
      {

      "line_year":"2012",

     "comment_list":[

        {

        "action":"Action1",

        "group":"group1",

        "comment":"comment1"

        }

         ]

       },

         {

          "line_year":"2020",

         "comment_list":[

          {

            "action":"Action2",

            "group":"group2",

            "comment":"comment2"

          }

         ]

       }

      ] 

    }
```

Comment: Yes, Java will do it, did you work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Talend with a tWriteJSONField, and some tricks.

Firstly, you'll have to add a column with a matching criteria for all of your lines (here I have named it "regroup" :

[image]

Then you have actually 3 nested array of objects : use @class "array" and element@class "object" to declare them in your tree :

"element", "array","object","class" are all reserved words. Pay attention to the syntax.
[image]

Then use your "regroup" column as "group by" in twriteJsonFIELD : this way you can regroup all lines in only one in the component output.
[image]
[image]